# Installing / removing encfs

Tags: macos, homebrew, sudo

I'm trying to install encfs, for which I need brew. I installed brew, but installing encfs is a pain.

```
bash-3.2$ brew install osxfuse
Warning: osxfuse-2.6.2 already installed, it's just not linked
bash-3.2$ brew link --overwrite osxfuse
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/osxfuse/2.6.2... Warning: Could not link osxfuse. 
Unlinking...
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/include/osxfuse/fuse/fuse_opt.h
bash-3.2$ ls -l /usr/local/include/osxfuse/fuse/fuse_opt.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  7187 17 Dec  2011 /usr/local/include/osxfuse/fuse/fuse_opt.h
```

How can I get this working? Using `sudo` is not allowed.

Comment: Could you run `ls -l /usr/local/include/osxfuse/fuse/fuse_opt.h` and paste the output?

Comment: @onik A [helpful user](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/72067/newton) posted the output as an answer, so I edited it into the flow of the question. Thanks Newton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems like osxfuse has been installed already, outside of brew, and with the root user. Since the permissions of the file are `-rw-r--r--`, you don't have write permissions to the file. This means that brew can't override the necessary files, and can't install osxfuse.

The only solution would be to use sudo or single user mode, and if it's not allowed, you can't install osxfuse with brew.

Have you tried installing encfs directly from brew? As far as I can see, the only dependencies are `rlog` and `boost`, but then again, I already had osxfuse installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the "permission denied" problem using this command: `sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local`

The easiest way to install encfs is using "brew install encfs". This will install all the dependencies (gettext ✔, boost ✔, rlog ✔, osxfuse) automatically.

Follow the instructions on this website to correctly [install encfs on Mac](http://ninjatips.com/encrypt-dropbox-using-encfs/).